# Grails: add a build task for compilation

Tags: grails, build, code-generation, amazon-swf

I'm using grails 2.4.4.
Some of my classes are annotated and a APT (annotation processing tool) has to process these annotations during compilation to generate some sources.

I was able to get everything done with the workaround of creating a maven pom.xml by running `grails generate-pom` and from there add specific plugins and configure them.

Is there a possibility to use the built-in grails compiler config `BuildConfig.groovy` to reach the same goal without the detour via maven pom.xml?

To be more specific, I'm creating a workflow with AWS SWF. And SWF uses annotations that should generate some client classes. Therefor in the pom.xml I added this. It works perfectly when I run `mvn compile`:

```
<build>
...
    <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>src/generated</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.amazonaws.eclipse.simpleworkflow.asynchrony.annotationprocessor.AsynchronyDeciderAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.9.34</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
                        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3.21</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
...
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out my self how to to it within grails.
Basically I created a script that you can call with the grails command. This script is nothing else but a `gant` script with which you can interfere with ant. Plus I had to add libraries to the `libs` folder in grails in order to have them in the classpath.

These are the steps:

1. Create a new grails script

   `grails create-script generateSources` This will create a script called GenerateSources.groovy into your grails scripts directory
2. Edit the `GenerateSources.groovy` file

   `includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsCompile")
   target(generateSources: "Generates sources for SWF workflow") {
       ant.delete(dir:"src/generated/java")
       ant.delete(dir:"target/generated-classes")
       depends(compile)
       ant.mkdir(dir:"src/generated/java")
       ant.mkdir(dir:"target/generated-classes")
       ant.javac(destdir:"target/generated-classes", classpathref:"grails.compile.classpath", source:"1.7", target:"1.7"){
           compilerarg(value:"-proc:only")
           compilerarg(value:"-s")
           compilerarg(value:"src/generated/java")
           src(path:"src/java")
       }
   }
   setDefaultTarget(generateSources)`

This includes references and tasks from the GrailsCompile script, deletes some folders (in case you re-run this script), calls the compile task from the native grails gant, creates the necessary target folders

4. Copy the necessary jars to the grails lib folder. In my case I had to copy the `aws-java-sdk-flow-build-tools-1.9.34.jar` which includes the Annotation processor and another dependence `freemarker-2.3.18.jar`. Javac will automatically call the correct APT in order to process the annotations in the the folder `src/java`
5. Run the script
   `grails generateSources` which will run the compile task and your new task

Open:
I'd like to hook up this task automatically when grails compile is called. I'm still working on that thoug.